# Find All Extension Methods for HTMLHelper, URLHelper and AJAXHelper Types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-2

Looking to find a way with Object Browser (in Visual Studio, or another tool) to find all of the extension methods defined for HTMLHelper, URLHelper and AJAXHelper. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out...

First, open object browser and go to the command "Edit Custom Conponent Set..."

[image]

Then add the MVC dll component...

[image]

Be sure the Browse drop down has "Custom Component Set" selected and "Show Extension Members" is selected...

[image]

Then perform the search on HtmlHelper and it will appear with the extension methods that are defined for the HtmlHelper data type

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense populates available extension methods on instances, and static methods from the Helper class itself.

[image: HtmlHelper Intellisense] [image: Instance Intellisense]

Comment: But it doesn't give me a way to see all of the overloads at the same time. I want to see them in the object browser.